# "mvn spring-boot:run": "/health" endpoint with project version

Tags: spring-boot

I'd like to use Spring Boot's actuator endpoint `/info` to show project metadata such as the Maven-provided project version.

To do so, I followed the [appropriate part in Spring Boot's documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-application-info-automatic-expansion-maven).

The shown solution works for me when my Spring Boot application starts up with `java -jar [...]`.

Just as the documentation says, it doesn't work when the application starts up with `mvn spring-boot:run` — in that case, my `/info` endpoint reports `"version":"@project.version@"`.

The documentation mentions that one has to properly configure Spring Boot's Maven plugin, but I could not find any information about doing so.

How can I configure my Maven project in order to have a `mvn spring-boot:run`-started Spring Boot application to show project metadata?

Answer (score 0):

Configure the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` with `<addResources>false</addResources>`.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <configuration>
    <addResources>false</addResources>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

[Source](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/maven-plugin/usage.html#Running_the_application)